# Мой бот не может выйти из функции isnumeric()

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Здраствуйте мой бот не может выйти из функции isnumeric(), когда пользователь отправляет "Ставка x2" то бот отправляет ему "Некорректная ставка!", а должен выйти из этой функции и умножить сумму ставку на 2 и вывести сумму ставки. Подскажите пожалуйста как это можно сделать.

```
        money = 100
        monstavka = None
        monwin = 0
        dostatok_money = None
        if msg == "1" or msg == "отмена":
            keyboard = VkKeyboard(one_time=True)
            keyboard.add_button("Игры")
            keyboard.add_line()
            keyboard.add_button("Промокод")
            keyboard.add_button("Бонус❤")
            keyboard.add_button("Инфа")
            keyboard.add_line()
            keyboard.add_button("Вывод")
            keyboard.add_button("Пополнение")

            send_some_msg(id, "Ты попал в главное меню DoubleX!", keyboard)

        if msg == "игры" or msg == "назад":
            game = VkKeyboard(one_time=True)
            game.add_button("Монетка")
            game.add_button("Hilo ")
            game.add_button("Минёр ")
            game.add_line()
            game.add_button("Отмена")
            send_some_msg(id, "Тебе решать...", game)
        
        if msg == "монетка":
            send_some_msg(id, "Введите сумму ставки!")          
            for event in longpoll.listen():                 
                if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
                    if event.to_me and event.text:
                        msg = event.text.lower()
                        if msg.isnumeric():
                            monstavka = int(msg)
                            if monstavka <= money:
                                dostatok_money = True
                                monstavka = int(msg)
                            else:
                                monstavka = None
                                dostatok_money = False                      
                        else :
                            otmena = VkKeyboard(one_time=True)
                            otmena.add_button("Отмена")
                            send_some_msg(id, "Некорректная ставка!", otmena)
                                
                        if dostatok_money and msg.isnumeric():                  
                            moneta = VkKeyboard()
                            moneta.add_button("Ставка x2")
                            moneta.add_button("Забрать")
                            moneta.add_button("Ставка x0.5")
                            moneta.add_line()
                            moneta.add_button("Орёл")
                            moneta.add_button("Решка")
                            moneta.add_line()
                            moneta.add_button("Назад")
                            send_some_msg(id, "Удачной игры!", moneta)
                            msg = event.text.lower()

                            if msg == "cтавка x2":
                                monstavka * 2
                                send_some_msg(id, "Ваша ставка: ", monstavka)

                        if dostatok_money == False:
                            otmena = VkKeyboard(one_time=True)
                            otmena.add_button("Отмена")
                            send_some_msg(id, "Недостаточно монет!", otmena)
                            break
```

Comment: А вы считаете, что `"cтавка x2"` — это число?

Comment: Нет это не число я вообще запутался чуть чуть

Comment: как сделать чтоб `msg.isnumeric()` больше не было `isnumeric()` ?